# instance variables not working right in javascript class for incremental game

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend, javascript-objects

I'm working on a incremental game made in Javascript and I'm running into an issue that I do not understand. It seems like I'm unable to access instance variables in my class methods.

```
export default class Store {
  constructor() {
    this.fishPole = {
      price: 50,
      cps: 0.5,
      amount: 0
    };

    this.net = {
      price: 300,
      cps: 2,
      amount: 0
    };

    this.boat = {
      price: 2500,
      cps: 15,
      amount: 0
    };

    this.crew = {
      price: 21000,
      cps: 120,
      amount: 0
    };

    this.yacht = {
      price: 180000,
      cps: 900,
      amount: 0
    };

    this.factory = {
      price: 1000000,
      cps: 8000,
      amount: 0
    };

    this.portal = {
      price: 10000000,
      cps: 70000,
      amount: 0
    };

    //this creates a list of objects
    this.storeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("buyBtn");
  }
  
  store(fishCount) {
    this.storeBtns[0].addEventListener("click", function(price) {
      if (fishCount >= this.fishPole.price) {
        fishCount -= this.fishPole.price;
        console.log("working");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and the main file

```
 import Store from "/src/store.js";

let fishCount = 0;
let lifeTimeFishCount = 0;
let cps = 0;
//cookies per click
let cpc = 1;

const fishCountSite = document.getElementById("fishCount");
const cpsSite = document.getElementById("fpsCounter");
const goFishing = document.getElementById("fishBtn");
const storeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("buyBtn");

let store = new Store();

function onClick() {
  fishCount += cpc;
  lifeTimeFishCount += cpc;
  return fishCount;
}

function main() {
  goFishing.addEventListener("click", function() {
    onClick();
    fishCountSite.innerHTML = fishCount;
  });
  store.store(fishCount);
}

main();
```

When I activate the event 'click' on `this.storebtn[0]` I get the error `Cannot read property 'price' of undefined`. To me this seems like its saying that `this.fishPole` is not defined and I don't know why this would be the case here, and I've tried doing this in multiple ways to fix it and I haven't been able to. I'm really lost as to why this is happening.

Comment: storebtn is an array of elements with classname = "buyBtn". Maybe this elements are not present in your HTML structure when code runs.

Comment: @danielarend Maybe im understanding you wrong but the issue seems to be that `this.fishPole` is seen as undefined which is a object that I made in the constructor for the store class. I can activate the event `click` on the storeBtn elements but I get the error `Cannot read property 'price' of undefined` reffering to this line `if (fishCount >= this.fishPole.price)`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapp all your code in window.onload except the import of Store:

```
import Store from "/src/store.js";
window.onload = ()=>{

    let fishCount = 0;
    let lifeTimeFishCount = 0;
    let cps = 0;
    //cookies per click
    let cpc = 1;

    const fishCountSite = document.getElementById("fishCount");
    const cpsSite = document.getElementById("fpsCounter");
    const goFishing = document.getElementById("fishBtn");
    const storeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("buyBtn");

    let store = new Store();

    function onClick() {
      fishCount += cpc;
      lifeTimeFishCount += cpc;
      return fishCount;
    }

    function main() {
      goFishing.addEventListener("click", function() {
        onClick();
        fishCountSite.innerHTML = fishCount;
      });
      store.store(fishCount);
    }

    main();

}
```

this error is caused because your document is not already loaded, so there are no elements when your code is tryng to get the elements, probably you have your `script type = module` in head tag and not in the end of the body, so this causes the error, don't move the code in html, only wrap your js code in window.onload.

Comment: I did this and now nothing at all works. Just html and css being displayed none of the JavaScript works when I do this. I also did have my link to the JavaScript before the closing body tag.

Comment: Are you running your script in a server?, remember that using import declaration and script type = module in your document needs to be running in a server, otherwise will not works.

Comment: Hey, i tried your code and it's working when i wrapp it in a window.onload, make sure that you are correctly getting the elements with the class "buyBtn", i think you have misstyped something in your html.

Comment: I'm not running in a server. I started working on this project before I looked into anything to do with server side code, and I made it on codesandbox.io. I was planning to to do it all on that website and once its done implement the server stuff I learned from a node.js tutorial I watched. Is that not a possible or effective way of doing this?

Comment: The import statement of ES6 requires to run in a server, but yes there is an easy way to run your code normally without uploading it to a page, so you can download nodejs and install with npm a package called http-server (install it globally using -g flag), once you have been installed http-server, change to your directory by cmd where you have your index.html file and type http-server -c-1 -o

Comment: Also in your index.html you need to add the attribute type = "module" to your main script file where you are importing the class.

Comment: Ah another one thing: change the src "/src/store.js" to "./src/store.js" otherwise you will have an error, this is because the import syntax require at minimum a ./ or ../ at the start of the route to load the file.

Comment: Ah doesn't matter about server side, this http-server is a simple local server that you can run like xampp but this is simpliest than xampp, is like the "proccessor" to make this thing works, but you don't need to make any operation using server side scripting.

Comment: Hey I got the solution you gave me for this issue to work, but I have one issue. When I run the program using the npm http-server package my CSS doesn't work. This is my stylesheet link: `<link real="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/css" />` all the image sources are working fine, but there is no CSS.

Comment: You don't need to put './' to refer to a stylesheet, also you have to check if your path of your stylesheet is correct, you only need './' or '../' to load JAVASCRIPT files with the ES6 import statement in a .js file, ohhh i see you have a typo!, you have typed: real = "stylesheet" instead of: rel = "stylesheet"